# How to Preserve Background Filter Across Navigations in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, navigation

I'm working on a multi-page Flutter web app where I intend to maintain a consistent visual theme across all pages. Specifically, I aim to preserve a backdrop filter effect (a blur effect) applied to the background of the first page, even as the user navigates to subsequent pages. However, I've encountered an issue where the background becomes progressively darker with each navigation.

To give you a better idea, here are the scenarios across three web pages:

**Web page #1:**

This is the initial page where I've applied a `BackdropFilter` with `ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2)` to achieve a blur effect. The background is transparent, and navigation to other pages is enabled through a `GestureDetector` widget triggering a dialog.

[image]

**Code for Web Page #1:**

```
return BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Container(...
       GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {                                     
showDialog(   context: 
context, builder: 
(ctx) => 
SignUpNameEmailPassword()
);  
},
```

**Web Page #2 and #3:**

Similar navigation logic is applied here, with `GestureDetector` widgets leading to new dialogs/pages. Unfortunately, after navigating from the first page, the background blur effect is maintained, but the backdrop becomes darker with each transition, which is not the intended behaviour.

**Web page #2:**

[image]

**Code for Web Page #2**

```
 Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
             GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                context: context,
               builder: (ctx) => WeSentYouAnEmail()); },
                  child: Container(
                     child: Center(
                         child: Icon(                                     Icons.arrow_forward,
                    size: 40,
                    color: Color(0xff7E7E7E),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
```

**Web page #3:**

[image]

**Code snippets for Web Page #2 and #3:** Follow a similar pattern, primarily differing in the content within `GestureDetector` widgets.

I'm puzzled about how to maintain the initial blur effect without deepening the background color as the user progresses through the app. My goal is to ensure that the backdrop's visual effect from **Web Page #1** remains consistent across all navigations.

Any insights or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Navigator push and pop might solve, if not you can use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the second, third and so on [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) calls with property `barrierColor` to `Colors.transparent`. Something like below:

```dart
showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (ctx) => SignUpNameEmailPassword());
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that each dialog is getting stacked. Before you call a new showDialog do

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

So you remove the previous pop up and add a new one.

Please note that you should be calling navigator.pop only if the dialog is displayed elseit will pop the main screen

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you push each page what makes the background darker.

You can try to navigate bewtween your pages like this.

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage());
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

This will push and replace the last page of the stack.